# using libcurl to monitor state of a network

Tags: c, libcurl

I need a program that polls a site every second and responds if the site doesnt respond in 15 seconds. I made the following hack from an example program. On a dry run, it printed 7 times in 15 seconds. Cant I make curl_easy_perform wait for 15 seconds before responding?

```
int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
char *postthis="moo mooo moo moo";

curl = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.1.101");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postthis);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, (long)strlen(postthis));
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);

while(1)
{
    Sleep(1000);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if(res!= CURLE_OK)
        printf("nada \n");

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sleep(15000 - timeTakenForCurlInMs);
```

Comment: will try to implement THAT, there are inbuilt functions. Nailed the Sleep() and transfer times, then there is always a small processing time too. That wont matter too much.

Answer (score 2):

It was a dumb hack that *fails* every second. It was based on the POST tutorial. I hacked the GET stuff and it works fine.

```
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://URL_HERE");
    **curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);**

 while(1)
{
    Sleep(1000);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if(res== CURLE_OK) printf("\n\n yeah \n");
    else printf("\n\n nada \n");

}
    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```